# Programmatically open multiple tabs in Chrome using information from text file

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I have a txt file with X numbers of lines. 
I want read all the lines and then open a url: http://www.mywebsite.com/? + value of my line. 
How can I do that? 
Chrome will open a new tab with the value of my url + text of line. I am opening Chrome with `System.Diagnostic.`

I have a problem because chrome open X tabs... I want to open a tab for every line in my txt file... 
Code:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file =
   new System.IO.StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\logs.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "http://www.example.com/?" + line);            
}
file.Close();
```

Comment: Can you post your code So we can see what you are doing?

Comment: You should probably look into HttpClient, if you don't want to open the browser.

Comment: What exactly does Chrome do at the moment?  You say you have X lines, and Chrome opens X tabs - which sounds like what you want: _"I want to open a tab for every line..."_  I'm confused

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse yup but X times the same tab...

Comment: I dont think you can shell out and make a tab in a already created window, you might be able write a html file with js to call window.open on each url in an array then close itself. that would pop all the urls in the same window tab